# How to use variables from other modules in Terraform: Adding Host Project id to the Service Projects. (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops

My infrastructure its composed by a **Host Project** and several **Service Project**s that are using its *Shared VPC*.

I have refactored my `.tf` files of my infrustructure as it follows:

```
├── env
|   ├── dev
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── variables.tf
│   ├── pre
│   └── pro
├── host
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
└── modules
    ├── compute
    ├── network
    └── projects
```

The order of creation of the infrastructure is:

1. `terraform apply` in /host
2. `terraform apply` in /env/dev *(for instance)*

In the `main.tf` of the host directory I have created the VPC and enabled Shared VPC hosting:

```
# Creation of the hosted network
resource "google_compute_network" "shared_network" {
  name                    = var.network_name
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  project                 = google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host_project.project
  mtu                     = "1460"
 
}

# Enable shared VPC hosting in the host project.
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "host_project" {
  project    = google_project.host_project.project_id
  depends_on = [google_project_service.host_project]
}
```

The issue comes when I have refer to the Shared VPC Network in the **Service Projects**.

In the `main.tf` from `env/dev/` I have set the following:

```
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" "service_project_1" {
  host_project    = google_project.host_project.project_id
  service_project = google_project.service_project_1.project_id

  depends_on = [
    google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.host_project,
    google_project_service.service_project_1,
  ]
}
```

### QUESTION

How do I refer to the **Host Project ID** from another directory in the Service Project?

### What I have tried so far

1. I have thought of using [Ouput Values](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs) and [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources):

   In the `host/outputs.tf` declared as an output the Project ID as:

   ```
   output "project_id" {
       value = google_project.host_project.project_id
    }
   ```

   But then I end up not knowing how to implement this output in my `env/dev/main.tf`
2. I have thought on Data Sources and, in the `env/dev/main.tf` fetch for the Host Project ID. But then, in order to fetch it, I would need its name (which breaks the purpose of providing it in a programatic way if I have to hardcode it).

What should I try next? What I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files under the `env/dev` folder can't see anything above it, only any referenced modules.
You *could* refactor the `host` folder into a module to allow access to it's outputs... **but** that adds a risk that the host will be destroyed whenever you destroy a dev environment.
I would try running `terraform output -raw project_id` after creating the host and piping it to a text file or environment variable. Then using that as the input for a new "host_project" or similar variable in the 'env/dev' deployment.